# How to use setSortOrderProvider in Grid Vaadin 8?

Tags: grid, vaadin, vaadin8

Im trying to use Grid Component. I need to define the order of a column, I'm using this proyect:
https://github.com/vaadin/tutorial/tree/v8-step4

And I add this code:

```
Column name = grid.addColumn(customer -> customer.getFirstName() + " " + customer.getLastName())
    .setCaption("Name")
    .setSortOrderProvider(direction -> Stream.of(
            new QuerySortOrder("lastName", direction)
            ));

grid.setSortOrder(GridSortOrder.asc(name));
```

But I'm not getting the expected results, I'm getting ordered by firstName and then by lastName but i need the results ordered by lastName.

Have you had the same problem? How have you solved it?

Thank you.

Comment: Your `Grid` is using an in memory data provider like `ListDataProvider`?

Comment: Hi Steffen, Thanks for asking. I'm using setItems:

List<Customer> customers = service.findAll(filterText.getValue());
grid.setItems(customers);

Comment: Ok, do you set the default sort columns? I mean if you don't want to click on the column header for sorting, you need to call `setSortOrder` on your `Grid` on initialization.

Comment: I try to add one but i get the same result with or without using the setSortOrder: grid.setSortOrder(GridSortOrder.asc(name));

Comment: Can you provide all your grid code including the customer bean code?

Comment: Hi Steffen, I modify the question adding the proyect that I'm using (Vaadin Tutorial) and the code that I'm using to try to sort the column. Thanks for your time  ^_^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I digged into the code and found out that you need you need to call `setComparator` instead of the `setSortOrderProvider`. The former is intended for in-memory data providers. Unfortunately, it's a little bit confusing and not really well documented.

Answer (score 3):

I use this implementation of setComparator and it's working.  : )

```
Column name = grid.addColumn(customer -> customer.getFirstName() + " " + customer.getLastName())
        .setCaption("Name")
        .setComparator(new SerializableComparator<Customer>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Customer arg0, Customer arg1) {
                return arg0.getLastName().compareTo(arg1.getLastName());
            }
        });
```

With Lambda:

```
.setComparator((customer0, customer1) -> {
            return customer0.getLastName().compareTo(customer1.getLastName());
        });
```

and this other option:

```
Column name = grid.addColumn(customer -> customer.getFirstName() + " " + customer.getLastName())
        .setCaption("Name")
        .setComparator(grid.getColumn("lastName").getComparator(SortDirection.ASCENDING));
```